# How to seperate an array value and put into DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array which looks like this,

```
[{'interval': '1',
'paramlist': [{'PARAMCODE': 'P7-3-5-2-0', 'UNIT': 'k', 'VALUE': '0'},
            {'PARAMCODE': 'P2-1-3-4-0', 'UNIT': 'A', 'VALUE': '0'}]},
{'interval': '2',
'paramlist': [{'PARAMCODE': 'P7-3-5-2-0', 'UNIT': 'k', 'VALUE': '0'},
            {'PARAMCODE': 'P2-1-3-4-0', 'UNIT': 'A', 'VALUE': '0'}]},
```

and it goes on till so many more interval.

How to iterate and put this value in dataframe in pandas having different columns as interval, paramcode ,unit and value ?

This is something I have done

```
D4 = root.find('UTILITYTYPE').find('D4')
dayProfileRequested = {'DATE': dateRequested, 'IPlist': None}
  for dayprofile in D4:
if dayprofile.attrib['DATE'] != dateRequested:
    continue
else: 
    ipList = []
    for ip in dayprofile:
        ipDict = {'interval': ip.attrib['INTERVAL']}
        paramList = []
        for param in ip:
            paramDict = {'PARAMCODE': param.attrib['PARAMCODE'], 'VALUE': param.attrib['VALUE'],
                         'UNIT': param.attrib['UNIT']}
            paramList.append(paramDict)                
        ipDict['paramlist'] = paramList
        ipList.append(ipDict)
    dayProfileRequested['IPlist'] = ipList
    break  pprint(dayProfileRequested)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? SO is *not* a free coding service.

Comment: This is actually stupidly simple. Do you mind showing me what you've done?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: can I add new Time variable and increment it by 30 mins in the same code for each interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list is referenced by `x`, you can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) with the `record_path` and `meta` parameters -

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(x, record_path=['paramlist'], meta=['interval'])
df

    PARAMCODE UNIT VALUE interval
0  P7-3-5-2-0    k     0        1
1  P2-1-3-4-0    A     0        1
2  P7-3-5-2-0    k     0        2
3  P2-1-3-4-0    A     0        2
```

---

One recommendation I have for allcomers is that, if you're working with JSON, use pandas' JSON parser library (AKA, `json_normalizr`). Most JSON structures are simple enough to be work with an out-of the box usage of the API. Meanwhile, some other structures (such as this), need a little more work. And that's fine. You can figure it out easily enough through trial and error.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the answer, it worked for me, just now read about that library.

Comment: just 1 more thing, can I bring 'interval' column to first

Comment: @Noumi Sure you can. `v = df['interval']; del df['interval']; df.insert(0, 'interval', v)`. Alternatively, just set the index: `df = df.set_index('interval')`